# sidebar between main and modal div

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my website, I have the main div (where I have all my contents) and a hidden div (used to show detail about some content when the user select once).

The problem is that I can't have that : "When the user clic on one content or item, modal div is showed (in front end using z-index :) ) and the slidebar in the right of screen can be used to scroll in this modal (not to scroll the back end content). And when modal div is closed, this scrollbar will be used to scroll the main page contents".

This is what I exactly want to get : http://pinterest.com/rasagy/font-picker/

Comment: No code provided? Tisk.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ read how to implement jquery ui, there is the dialogbox, and  you set a high and all, scrollbars, panels, content, etc.

To call it you just do something like `$( "#dialog" ).dialog();`

where dialog its the ID of the div that you want to show up in the modal box.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using Bootstrap Twitter in my website and its modal div. And I want to find a compatible solution :)

Comment: The solution : create two divs in the baground (the first fixed and colored) and the second is the container of our modal data with transparent background and absolute propriety :)

Answer (score 0):

What you would want is to make the "modal div" the full size of the page

```
div.modal{
    ...
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

and then make the overflow of body hidden on click. this would give the illusion that the scroll bar hasnt changed when in reality it has.

```
body.hidescroll{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Then when you close the modal div just remove the class from body.
all the javascript for this is pretty trivial so I haven't included it.

Comment: I don't want to have modal div in full screen. The modal have a background div that will collapse the main div. All my div modal's content must be showed (using the same scroll bar as a main content div) !

Comment: Well you linked to pintrest saying it's exactly what you want, this will get that effect. as far as what you've said you could do something similar in hiding the contents scroll, then make a "fullscreen" div and display a second inner div where you want it to show up.

Comment: Tks. I found the solution :

Answer (score 0):

you can operate the window scrollTop only